# Rasterize shapefile using another raster's size and resolution

Tags: qgis, gdal, rasterization

Rasterizing a vector (shp) I face the following problem: I want my output file (the rasterized vector) to have the same resolution and dimensions as an existing raster.

If I understand the interface correctly, the option "keep size and resolution of existing layer" should do this job. However, there is no option to choose an existing layer. Any hints?

Of course, I can achieve (at least approximately) what I want to do **using the `–te` and `–tr`** parameters. However it would be interesting to know if and how the "keep seize and resolution of existing layer" works.

Comment: The gdal_rasterize command can use an existing raster; before 1.8 the raster had to exist before running the command. If you can copy the existing raster and then supply it to the gdal_rasterize then it should do what you want.

Comment: Sorry Michael, I´m afraid I don´t understand what you mean. I currently use this parametres: **gdal_rasterize -a adecuado -l vector_2 -tr 15.00 -15.00 -te 403326.00 1853140.00 461517.00 "...\\vector_2.shp" ".../output.tif"** This works. However, my question would be if have to put this values (resolution, extension) manually, or can I use the "keep size and resolution of existing layer" option to load this values automatically from a given raster file?

Comment: What I am saying is that if you copy *existing.tif* to *output.tif* and then use gdal_rasterize (with no fancy options) "...\\vector_2.shp" ".../output.tif" it will use the existing raster thus keeping the cell size and extent.

Comment: You mean that I have to **overwrite an already existing raster**, that has the extension and resolution I want?

Comment: Yes, that is the intent. The C function for rasterize (GDALRasterizeGeometries) must have an existing raster; if you supply a raster path to the tool that doesn't exist the first thing it does is create the raster and then rasterize using that.

Comment: It does not overwrite existing raster it just burns pixels into it. Create a background raster from a big polygon that covers your data as all white and you should be fine.

Comment: Finally tried what you guys suggested and your right - **burning an existing raster works**. As user30184 mentioned, using a uniform raster (with just 1 value) helps. Thank you! Maybe you can post our tip again so I can accept it as the answer!?

Answer (score 1):

In QGIS, you should be able to achieve this with the GDAL ***Rasterize (Overwrite with Attribute)*** algorithm (available in the *Processing Toolbox*).

1. Make a copy of your raster layer (*Layer-> Save as...*) - specify a file name (e.g. `baseraster.tif`) and location.
2. Run the ***Rasterize (Overwrite with Attribute)***
   algorithm.

   1. Choose the vector layer you would like to rasterize as *Input vector layer*.
   2. Choose `baseraster.tif` as *Input raster layer*.
   3. Choose the attribute of the input vector layer to use for the rasterization in *Field to use for burn in value*.
   4. Do ***not*** tick/check *Add burn in values to existing raster values*.

The output raster should have the same resolution, extent and `no data` cells as the base raster, and cell/pixel values should be taken from the input vector layer.